# Using delay() with removeClass()

Tags: jquery, css, getuikit

How do I delay the removal of a css class in jQuery?

Here is my code

```
$(this).addClass("uk-form-danger").delay(5000).removeClass("uk-form-danger");
```

The above code does nothing. I can add the class with the following code

```
$(this).addClass("uk-form-danger");
```

and I can remove it with

```
$(this).removeClass("uk-form-danger");
```

but I can't delay the removal of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily accomplish that with a setTimeout:

```
var myItem = $(this);

myItem.addClass("uk-form-danger");
setTimeout( function(){ myItem.removeClass("uk-form-danger"); }, 5000 );
```

Answer (score 3):

jquery delay is only intended to use with animations, you will not be able to delay the removeClass this way, use setTimeout instead:

```
var $el = $('#myId');
$el .addClass("uk-form-danger")
setTimeout(function(){
    $el .removeClass("uk-form-danger");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using setTimeout instead of delay?

```
var myObject = $(this);

myObject.addClass("uk-form-danger");

setTimeout(function()
{
    myObject.removeClass("uk-form-danger");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This wont work. What do you thing 'this' is inside the timeout function's scope?

Comment: Then you just create a variable and store it there, then refer to it likeso:

`var myObject = $(this);
myObject.removeClass("uk-form-danger");`

Comment: Well... that would be correct. But your answer is not doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using setTimeout

```
var self = $(this);
self.addClass('uk-form-danger');
setTimeout(function () {
    self.removeClass('uk-form-danger');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This wont work. What do you thing 'this' is inside the timeout function's scope?

Answer (score 0):

The **easiest** way is to use [jQueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/).

`.delay()` only works for methods in the effects queue. You need to place your `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` into the default effects queue by including a duration.

> $(this).addClass("uk-form-danger",
>   **250**).delay(5000).removeClass("uk-form-danger", **250**);